# How to Load a Pre-Trained Model from GitHub?

Tags: github, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, pre-trained-model

In Deep Learning we have **pre-trained models** in `keras.applications.` What if we want to load a pre-trained model available on github in Google Colab? What would be steps then? Does `load_model` work in this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if the model is created with tf/keras you can use keras laod model function, or you can check tensorflow hub , pls note not every pre-trained model is callable in keras

Comment: @Yefet what if the pre-trained model is written in Pytorch?

Comment: there it tools for that like ONNX to convert models from framework to other but ive never used and im not sure about stablity

Comment: @Yefet Okay and if there is model made for unsupervised training, can we use it in supervised setting for feature extraction?